# How to remove leading and trailing whitespaces?

Tags: awk, whitespace, gsub, removing-whitespace

I'm using `awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,""); print;}' in.txt > out.txt` to remove both leading and trailing whitespaces.

The problem is the output file actually has trailing whitespaces! All lines are of the same length - they are right padded with spaces.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

The problem is probably due to the the fact that the trailing spaces are nor "normal" spaces but \x20 characters (DC4).

**UPDATE 2**

I used `gsub (/'[[:cntrl:]]|[[:space:]]|\x20/,"")` an it  worked.
Two strange things:

1. Why isn't \x20 considered a control character?
2. Using `'[[:cntrl:][:space:]\x20` does NOT work. Why?

Comment: UPDATE: perhaps these are not simple spaces, but DC4 control characters? The files originated from Windows.

Comment: `\x20` is a regular ASCII space. Control characters are `\x00` through `\x1F`.

Answer (score 27):

This command works for me:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 Yes, why not? ;-) You can even do: `awk '$1=$1' file.txt` isn't it?

Comment: @oHessling `$1=$1` will delete empty line

Comment: @eddi. `awk` will normalize a line by removing extra spaces. `$1=$1` trigger the action, otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: I think you should add that to the answer together with an explanation of what the 1 does.

Comment: @eddi The `1` is the same as `{print}`. It will print every line.

Comment: @kev : it does not work with GNU Awk 3.1.7 on CentOS 6.5 with ksh: `echo "foo;bar    ">tt && print "_$( awk -F";" -OFS";" '{$2=$2}1' tt)_"` gives `_foo;bar     _`. Did I miss something ? What is your setup, btw ?

Comment: So `awk '{$2=$2}1'` is equivalent to `awk '{$2=$2; print $0}'`. For some awks; this doesn't strip whitespaces on all awks (e.g.Mac system awk). Also, you need to explain the quirky idiom in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is OK for me.
You may have something else than `space` and `tabulation`...
`hexdump -C` may help you to check what is wrong:

```
awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,""); print;}' in.txt | hexdump -C | less
```

### UPDATE:

OK you identified DC4 (there may be some other control characters...)
Then, you can improve your command:

```
awk '{gsub(/^[[:cntrl:][:space:]]+|[[:cntrl:][:space:]]+$/,""); print;}' in.txt > out.txt
```

See `awk` manpage:

`[:alnum:]  Alphanumeric characters.`
  `[:alpha:]  Alphabetic characters.`
  `[:blank:]  Space or tab characters.`
**`[:cntrl:]  Control characters.`**
  `[:digit:]  Numeric characters.`
  `[:graph:]  Characters that are both printable and visible.  (A space is printable, but not visible, while an a is both.)`
  `[:lower:]  Lower-case alphabetic characters.`
  `[:print:]  Printable characters (characters that are not control characters.)`
  `[:punct:]  Punctuation characters (characters that are not letter, digits, control characters, or space characters).`
**`[:space:]  Space characters (such as space, tab, and formfeed, to name a few).`**
  `[:upper:]  Upper-case alphabetic characters.`
  `[:xdigit:] Characters that are hexadecimal digits.`

### Leading/Trailing `0x20` removal

For me the command is OK, I have tested like this:

```
$ echo -e "\x20 \tTEXT\x20 \t" | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 09 54 45 58 54 20  20 09 0a                 |  .TEXT  ..|
0000000b
$ echo -e "\x20 \tTEXT\x20 \t" | awk '{gsub(/^[[:cntrl:][:space:]]+|[[:cntrl:][:space:]]+$/,""); print;}' | hexdump -C
00000000  54 45 58 54 0a                                    |TEXT.|
00000005
```

However if you have `0x20` in the middle of your text 
=> then it is not removed. 
But this is not your question, isn't it?

Comment: I really thought this would work, but it didn't, I'm still left with all these "spaces" ASCII code 20 (int = 32).

Comment: Hello @user1194552. Please provide your `hexdump -C` output before and after `awk` processing. Then I can better understand your issue. Because when I try to test, it looks good for me :-)

Comment: What is your `awk --version`? I can test two versions: `GNU Awk 3.1.3` and `GNU Awk 3.1.5`. And please provide your `hexdump -C`. Then I can test the same thing as you.

Answer (score 1):

Your files probably have Windows line endings. That means that they end with `\r\n`, so matching a sequence of tabs and spaces at the end of the line won't work -- awk tries to match all the tabs and spaces that come *after* the `\r`. Try running the file through `tr -d "\r"` before sending it   to awk.

Answer (score 0):

Perl could be used:

```
perl -lpe 's/^\s*(.*\S)\s*$/$1/' in.txt > out.txt
```

`s/foo/bar/` substitute using regular expressions
`^` beginning of string
`\s*` zero or more spaces
`(.*\S)` any characters ending with a non-whitespace.  Capture it into $1
`\s*` zero or more spaces
`$` end of string