# awk output to file based on filter

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement, awk, filter

I have a big `CSV` file that I need to cut into different pieces based on the value in one of the columns.  My input file `dataset.csv` is something like this:

*NOTE*: edited to clarify that data is `,data,` no spaces.

```
action,action_type, Result
up,1,stringA
down,1,strinB
left,2,stringC
```

So, to split by `action_type` I simply do (I need the whole matching line in the resulting file):

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^1$/ {print}' dataset.csv >> 1_dataset.csv
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^2$/ {print}' dataset.csv >> 2_dataset.csv
```

This works as expected but I am basicaly travesing my original dataset twice. My original dataset is about 5GB and I have 30 `action_type` categories. I need to do this everyday, so, I need to script the thing to run on its own efficiently.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
# This is a file called myFilter.awk

{
action_type=$2;
if (action_type=="1") print $0 >> 1_dataset.csv;
else if (action_type=="2") print $0 >> 2_dataset.csv;
}
```

Then I run it as:

```
awk -f myFilter.awk dataset.csv
```

But I get nothing. Literally nothing, no even errors.  Which sort of tell me that my code is simply not matching anything or my print / pipe statement is wrong.

Comment: Is your field separator one `,` or one `,` followed by a space?

Comment: if you have a space after the comma and before the data (eg, `1` or `2`), and your `awk` input delimiter is just a comma, then your tests become `<space>1` == `1`, which is 'false'; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601021) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9175801) for ideas on trimming leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: @Cyrus, it is a `,`.  Thanks!

Comment: @markp-fuso, it does not have spaces. I just edited the question to make it clear. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the header line included in every output file? Do you have GNU awk (`awk --version`)?

Comment: @EdMorton,  I don't mind about the header line.  If I have it is OK, otherwise it is not a big deal.  I do have GNU awk: 5.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this awk to do this in a single command:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1{fn = $2 "_dataset.csv"; print >> fn; close(fn)}' file
```

Comment: Holy cow! This is brilliant @anubhava! It totally worked! Thank you!

Comment: That was an awesome way of contents extraction. The trick happens because of `print >> fn` part, which continuously appends the existed `fn` files as the original `file` progress.

Comment: Just make sure that any existing output files are deleted before running or `>>` will append to that existing file...

Comment: Hi @dawg. Yes, thanks for the reminder.  I am also going to test other methods to find out which one is more efficient.  In my 5GB file, this has been running for about 2 hours and I do not see it even close to be done (based on the size of the output files than at then their sum should match the size of the original file).

Comment: @Wilmar if you're looking for the fastest solution then update your question to say that. So far no-one has posted the fastest solution and chances are no-one will since you already accepted an answer. Also see my comment under your question and update your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton. I am adding that as a separate question for, in fact, my objective was not speed in the initial question.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk to handle many concurrently open files and without replicating the header line in each output file:

```
awk -F',' '{print > ($2 "_dataset.csv")}' dataset.csv
```

or if you also want the header line to show up in each output file then with GNU awk:

```
awk -F',' '
    NR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    !seen[$2]++ { print hdr > ($2 "_dataset.csv") }
    { print > ($2 "_dataset.csv") }
' dataset.csv
```

or the same with any awk:

```
awk -F',' '
    NR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    { out = $2 "_dataset.csv" }
    !seen[$2]++ { print hdr > out }
    { print >> out; close(out) }
' dataset.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

As currently coded the input field separator has not been defined.

Current:

```
$ cat myfilter.awk
{
action_type=$2;
if (action_type=="1") print $0 >> 1_dataset.csv;
else if (action_type=="2") print $0 >> 2_dataset.csv;
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ awk -f myfilter.awk dataset.csv
```

There are a couple ways to address this:

```
$ awk -v FS="," -f myfilter.awk dataset.csv
```

or

```
$ cat myfilter.awk
BEGIN {FS=","}
{
action_type=$2
if (action_type=="1") print $0 >> 1_dataset.csv;
else if (action_type=="2") print $0 >> 2_dataset.csv;
}

$ awk -f myfilter.awk dataset.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @markp-fuso.  This indeed works.  I anubhava 'anubhava' answer as correct for it was beautifully concise and straightforward.

Comment: @Wilmar  not a problem, anubhava is just too quick on that keyboard of his! :-)  and I was more interested in pointing out the issue with the original code

Comment: @mark-fuse.  Absolutely, that helps a lot!  Thanks again.